Automatically set parent terminal title as current buffer name
I'm running  Emacs in terminal with -nw option over i3 in Ubuntu 22.04.
I use emacs server to start automatically in background and create more emacs-clients from more parent gnome-shell terminals. It works fine, but over i3 I need rofi program that reads only terminal title. Rofi program doesn't see child process started from terminal such as Emacs frames. I need to change automatically parent gnome-shell title after the current buffer of its child Emacs frame. Unfortunately, the xterm-title package is no longer maintained. I tried something with
(suspend-emacs "set-title (buffer-name) && fg)

but it didn't work. Sometime, suspend-emacs asks to close the other opened emacs-clients. Sometime if it changes the gnome-shell title, when it returns in Emacs, the title remain unchanged. Has somebody got a great idea to solve this awkward situation? I know there is an i3 Emacs mode that change the behavior of i3 when on the current i3 window run Emacs frame, but I want to avoid a mess. Combining i3 with Emacs is a real mess, and for my clearness I want to use i3 totally independent from Emacs frame. For Vim buffer was simple to solve, I added some lines in .vimrc file and it changes its parent gnome-shell title perfectly.

Fortunately I solve it. https://github.com/CyberShadow/term-title has some functions and mode that seem to solve my answer.

Post the comment as answer and mark it as solved. Do not forget to show what functions did you used from the posted link. .
